# Paths.get(args[0]) does not work

Tags: java, path, arguments

How can I give a source file in args[0] and a target in args[1]? I created a source.txt and a target.txt in the same package and put "./source.txt" and "./target.txt" as arguments in the run configuration. But it throws the exception that "./source.txt" is not readdable.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumnetException: ./source.txt
```

What is worng?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import de.sb.javase.TypeMetadata;


/**
   * Demonstrates copying a file using a single thread.
*/
public final class FileCopyLinear {

/**
 * Copies a file. The first argument is expected to be a qualified source file name,
 * the second a qualified target file name. 
 * @param args the VM arguments
 * @throws IOException if there's an I/O related problem
 */
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    final Path sourcePath = Paths.get(args[0]);
    if (!Files.isReadable(sourcePath)) throw new IllegalArgumentException(sourcePath.toString());

    final Path sinkPath = Paths.get(args[1]);
    if (sinkPath.getParent() != null && !Files.isDirectory(sinkPath.getParent())) throw new IllegalArgumentException(sinkPath.toString());

    Files.copy(sourcePath, sinkPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

    System.out.println("done.");
}
}
```

Comment: "./source.txt" is not readdable ?? i hope implementers not made that spelling mistake.Always copy paste original stacktrace

Comment: What is "the exception" in detail (type, message, reasonably detailed stack trace)?

Comment: isn't args[0] the .java-file you are excetuting? or was that just in C++?

Comment: @MarcoForberg: `args[0]` is the first parameter passed to your jvm...

Comment: @Matthias : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumnetException: ./source.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relative file paths are not relative to the package of any class. They're relative to current directory, which is the directory from which the `java` command was executed to start you program.

So, if you're in the directory `/home/user1477955` and type

```
/home/user1477955 > java com.foo.bar.FileCopyLinear source.txt target.txt
```

it will search for the files `/home/user1477955/source.txt` and `/home/user1477955/target.txt`

Comment: you are totally right, thank you very much for the fast response

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
try {
        File file = new File(args[0]);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        //rest of your code
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File Read Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: If the path is wrong or the file is not readable, that will not help.